# PHP how to download file send by X-Sendfile?

Tags: php, x-sendfile

I have a WordPress site A and send zip file with [PHP-X-Sendfile](https://github.com/mostafaznv/php-x-sendfile), for example:
`https://a.com/?download=a` will download file `a.zip`[

```
if (!empty($_GET['download'])) {
    $xSendFile = new PhpXsendfile();
    $xSendFile->download(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/a.zip');
}
```

it's working perfectly.

and now I want to download it from WordPress site B. for example:
`https://b.com/?download=a` can download file from `https://a.com/?download=a`.

I tried methods below:

Method 1:

```
$file_url = 'https://a.com/?download=a';
$a = download_url($file_url, 3000);
die;
```

Result: Not working, and return WP_Error `A valid URL was not provided`.

Note: `download_url` is a built-in WordPress function for download external file.

Method 2:

```
$file_url = 'https://a.com/?download=a';
$xSendFile = new PhpXsendfile();
$xSendFile->download($file_url);`
```

Result: Not working, and got browser error 'This site can’t be reached'.

So I think the problem is how to download remote file send by X-sendfile?

Any ideas? thank you.

Comment: Without any code, there's not a lot that we can help with.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I updated example code:)